# R adding layers to a ggplot plot with vectors of different length

Tags: r, ggplot2, roc

I research this problem, and all tricks fail here. I am trying to build ROC curve in ggplot. Different models of machine learning return a different length of observations vectors. My goal is to gather them in one plot, color and put legend.

It is easy when all your data has the same X axis length - (number of observations). All x and y are in a range of [0 to 1]. A problem is a different number of observations. I'd like to avoid interpolating and coercing vectors to the same length because each observation carries important information.

So far I figured out that the best approach would be put new layers of lines on the same plot.

Maybe other types of plot? or specialized plots from other packages.

Please help. Thanks!

`ggplot(vector_1, aes(x, y ) ) + geom_line() + ???? new layers ???`

My goal is to obtain a plot like this but with more lines:
[image]

Here is vector1 - 34 observations:

**vector_1_x:**

0
0.02325581
0.02325581
0.04651163
0.04651163
0.06976744
0.09302326
0.11627907
0.13953488
0.1627907
0.18604651
0.20930233
0.23255814
0.25581395
0.27906977
0.30232558
0.3255814
0.37209302
0.39534884
0.41860465
0.44186047
0.46511628
0.48837209
0.51162791
0.53488372
0.62790698
0.65116279
0.74418605
0.76744186
0.86046512
0.90697674
0.93023256
0.97674419
1

**vector_1_y:**

0
0
0.1666667
0.1666667
0.3333333
0.3333333
0.3333333
0.3333333
0.3333333
0.3333333
0.3333333
0.3333333
0.3333333
0.3333333
0.3333333
0.3333333
0.5
0.5
0.5
0.6666667
0.6666667
0.6666667
0.6666667
0.6666667
0.6666667
0.6666667
0.8333333
0.8333333
0.8333333
1
1
1
1
1

Here is vector2 - 50 observations:

**vector_2_x:**

0
0
0.02325581
0.04651163
0.04651163
0.06976744
0.09302326
0.11627907
0.13953488
0.1627907
0.18604651
0.20930233
0.23255814
0.25581395
0.25581395
0.27906977
0.30232558
0.3255814
0.34883721
0.37209302
0.39534884
0.39534884
0.41860465
0.44186047
0.46511628
0.48837209
0.51162791
0.51162791
0.53488372
0.55813953
0.58139535
0.60465116
0.62790698
0.65116279
0.65116279
0.6744186
0.69767442
0.72093023
0.74418605
0.76744186
0.79069767
0.81395349
0.8372093
0.86046512
0.88372093
0.90697674
0.93023256
0.95348837
0.97674419
1

**vector_2_x:**

0
0.1666667
0.1666667
0.1666667
0.3333333
0.3333333
0.3333333
0.3333333
0.3333333
0.3333333
0.3333333
0.3333333
0.3333333
0.3333333
0.5
0.5
0.5
0.5
0.5
0.5
0.5
0.6666667
0.6666667
0.6666667
0.6666667
0.6666667
0.6666667
0.8333333
0.8333333
0.8333333
0.8333333
0.8333333
0.8333333
0.8333333
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1

Comment: Edit your post and paste the results of `dput(your.df.name)` and you will get more useful help.

Comment: `dat <- data.frame(x = c(vector_1_x, vector_2_x), y = c(vector_1_y, vector_2_y), name = rep(c('1','2'), each = c(length(vector_1_x), length(vector_2_x))), stringsAsFactors = F); ggplot(dat, aes(x = x, y = y, colour = name))+geom_line()`

Answer (score 4):

Put `vector_1` and `vector_2` into their own data frames like so:

```
df1 <- data.frame(x = vector_1_x, y = vector_1_y)
df2 <- data.frame(x = vector_2_x, y = vector_2_y)
```

Then you can specify a different `data.frame` for each `ggplot` layer:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_line(data = df1, aes(vector_1_x, vector_1_y), colour = "red") +
  geom_line(data = df2, aes(vector_2_x, vector_2_y), colour = "green")
```

### Update

What I wrote above originally is okay for a few lines but it will be much cleaner to put all the vectors in their own `data.frame` with an indicator variable stating which line it belongs to. This would look something like:

```
x    y    vector
1    1    "line1"
2    3    "line1"
3    6    "line1"
...  ...  ...
1    8    "line2"
2    6    "line2"
3    2    "line2"
...  ...  ...
```

Then in you can have a single `ggplot` layer:

```
ggplot(data = df) + geom_line(aes(x, y, colour = vector))
```

Comment: You can specify a `color` in `aes()`. Honestly though it would be better to put them all in the same `data.frame` with an extra variable specifying what line it is. That would make it more scalable. What I have is ok for 2-3 lines but can be unnecessarily verbose for many lines.

Comment: @bouncyball Ok I added that, also added a new version that will work better for many lines